# IntelliJ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Yes before you close this thread I have read all the same question threads saying I need to add `hamcrest` to classpath. I don't understand what that means or how to do it. I have JDK 14 and don't know why I'm having random problems now. I just want to do JUnit testing.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=50007:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Users\amanu\Documents\hackerman\cmsc420summer20\pqueue\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.1\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter\5.4.2\junit-jupiter-5.4.2.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.4.2\junit-jupiter-api-5.4.2.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.0.0\apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.1.1\opentest4j-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.4.2\junit-platform-commons-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-params\5.4.2\junit-jupiter-params-5.4.2.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.4.2\junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.2.jar;C:\Users\amanu\.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.4.2\junit-platform-engine-1.4.2.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 pqueue.StudentTests

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 18 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

**Edit**

My confusion was IntelliJ asking me to add the path of the hamcrest-core-1.3.jar file. hamcrest-core-1.3.jar is already within the Java JDK installation. I thought this meant that hamcrest was already being used in the project, and that was the incorrect assumption.

**Solution**

I went to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Looked for hamcrest within the JDK installation -> Added hamcrest-core-1.3.jar.

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies. Make sure all the required jars are present there. If not, add them.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what required jars are missing, or even if they were missing? And if they were missing, how would I add them?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-testing-libraries.html. It describes which libraries are needed and how to add them. You can also use Maven and Gradle to manage the dependencies and the IDE will import them automatically from your build files.

Comment: THANK YOU my source of confusion was the location of the hamcrest.jar that was already in my JDK installation. I went to Project Structure -> Dependencies -> Added hamcrest-core-1.3.jar. Does Maven and Gradle automatically handle that usually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-testing-libraries.html) describing which testing libraries are needed. And [another document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) describing how you can add them to the module dependencies.

Basically you locate the jars or download them, then go to the Project Structure | Modules | Dependecies tab, click the + button and specify the path to the jar file(s).

If you decide to use Maven or Gradle, testing dependencies are easier to add in the build files and all the transitive dependencies will be downloaded and configured automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try out following jar
 **hamcrest-2.2.jar**  - https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.hamcrest

Comment: What do I do now that I've downloaded it? I'm confused on the parts people tend to skip over :(

Comment: @user9448168 Did you read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency ? Does it answer your question? If not, what was not clear in the specified steps?

Comment: Your other comment with the link to configuring testing libraries gave me the location of hamcrest answered my question!